# Product sku not appearing on frontend

Tags: product, product-list, frontend, sku

I added product sku on to Product list page. Using below code:

```
<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getSku() , 'sku'); ?>
```

It was showing the sku like I wanted. But suddenly it disappeared. I checked the code, its there. But it is not showing up on frontend. then I tried

```
<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getData('sku') , 'sku'); ?>
```

also didn't work.

Comment: Just a note, in your second snippet it should be `getData` and not `getDate`. Do a `var_dump($_product->getSku())` to see if you get a value. It wouldn't just disappear.

Comment: var_dump dumping Null. Same website I have mirror copy that one showing properly.

Comment: Go to `System > Index Management` and refresh your indexes. Especially `Product Attributes` and `Product Flat Data`

Answer (score 1):

By going, System > Configuration > Catalog > FrontEnd and select "No" to "Use Flat Catalog Product" solved the problem.